# Proper way to create predicate for relationship for NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

If I have an album to songs one-to-many relationship, what is the proper way to set my fetchedresultscontroller to display songs for a given album?

Is my entity songs and my predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"album == %@", albumTitle]
```

Or is my entity albums with a different predicate that somehow reaches across to songs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your your song has a property `album`, which in turn has a property `title`:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"album.title == %@", albumTitle]
```

or if you want `malmo` to match `Malmö`, you'd need:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"album.title CONTAINS[cd] %@", albumTitle]
```

where `c` denotes case *insensitive* search and `d` denotes diacritic *insensitive* search.

For more information, refer to [Predicate Format String Syntax Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html).